# Custom Environment Variables in PHP

Tags: php, apache, variables, environment

Is there a way to set a custom variable such as `environment_name` in my apache vhost file that can be read via `$_ENV` or `ini_get("environment_name")`?

Comment: Is it running on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Linux (people run php/apache on windows?)

Comment: Yes, the numbnuts in my company do.

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, you need to change an `$_ENV` variable rather an one in `$_SERVER`. In that case the answer is OS-dependent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know if you

```
SetEnv MY_VAR 1
```

in your .htaccess file that you'll be able to

```
echo $_SERVER['MY_VAR']
```

in your PHP script and/or program.  If you can do it in .htacces, you can do it in your vhost configuration.

There's also php functions to set your [php ini values](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

I'm not sure about a way to populate $ENV, or is SetEnv will do it.  It's worth investigating a var_dump($ENV) with the above.

Comment: @Ian Note that `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV` are completely different.

Comment: Yeah, I really didn't care where I pull it from, as long as it's easily accessible. :)